# Getting data from a rails raw SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to use the results from a database query to test against the results from another query.

I have the following raw sql query

```
sail_query = "select s.id from sailings AS s
  INNER JOIN events on events.sailing_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN event_registers on events.id = event_registers.event_id
  where event_registers.event_id = #{event_register.event_id}
  and event_registers.user_id = #{event_register.user_id}"
@sail_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sail_query)
```

This produces

```
[{"id"=>1, 0=>1}]
```

Which is what I expect. I need the "id" to check it against another id, but I don't know have to 'get' it. I would have expected to call @sail_result.id in the view, but that returns

undefined method `id' for [{"id"=>1, 0=>1}]:Array

Any thoughts on what how I could do this? What I thought to be a 2 minute problem has escalated into hours of fruitless research.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it returns an array, you can do `@sail_result[0].id`to get that value.